# Xamarin Forms Map - VisibleRegion stays null until I drag/scroll the map

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

The only way to get a non-null value is by doing an action on the map from the screen, but I would like to get this data as soon as it's available. Also, is it possible to get every times that it changes something as an event? Then it would be able to call the `OnPropertyChanged` method of my `CustomMapRenderer`.

Tell me if you need more explanation !

Thank in advance